# Tricky module import with late init

Tags: python, module, import

I have such a simple module's structure:

```
mod1/
    __init__.py
    clsOne.py
    clsN.py
```

Where code looks like this:

```
__init__.py:
     # module init
     from clsOne import MyFirstCLass
     from clsN import NThCLass

     clshnd = MyFirstClass()
     ...
     nhnd = NThClass()

clsOne.py:
     class MyFirstClass( object ):
         pass
clsN.py:
     classNThClass( object ):
         pass
```

Now I use them as follows:

```
Way #1) 
    from mod1.clsOne import MyFirstClass
```

or:

```
Way #2) 
    from mod1 import clshnd
```

Is it possible to import name `clshnd` but in such a way that other handlers (i.e. `nhnd`) are initialized only on demand (when explicitelly imported)?
For now both: Way #1 and Way #2 cause module initialization call, means: also NThClass object is created. I would like to avoid it, because I have a lot of such classes and would like to avoid long init, however I would like to have simple access (Way #2) as well.
Is it possible at all or I have to redesign modules and files (remove from **init**)?

Zbigniew

Answer (score 0):

You just put the relevant code into a separate module.

```
mod1/
    __init__.py
    clsOne.py
    clsN.py
    foo.py
```

And then in `foo.py`:

```
from clsOne import MyFirstCLass
from clsN import NThCLass

clshnd = MyFirstClass()
...
nhnd = NThClass()
```